# Extending Backbone.Model through mixins

Tags: backbone.js, mixins

I'm recently started playing with Backbone.js. I want to apply custom validation mechanism to  my model classes and I decided to go with mixin classes. Now the question is it a good idea to attach the mixin to the `Backbone.Model` class like below,

```
_.extend(Backbone.Model.prototype, MyApp.ValidationMixin)
```

or can I create a base model `AppModel` from which all the application models extends and I'll attach the mixin to the base model.

```
var AppModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});
_.extend(AppModel.prototype, MyApp.ValidationMixin)
```

Is there any problem I'll face if I go with the first approach?

Comment: Since you are new to Backbone, i just want to point out that you should use the validate method: http://backbonejs.org/#Model-validate. It would work with both solutions, but i recommend the second.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the first approach is OK for this specific case (adding a Validation Mixin to the Backbone Model) but your validation Mixin may get erased by other libraries doing the same (it's sometimes hard to 'pick and choose' the functionality of additional Backbone libraries).

The second approach is safer and is the usual recommended approach as can be seen in various Backbone's app boilerplates.

Both are technically the same, as long as you live in your own little "app bubble".

Comment: Finally I got convinced by your answer "erased by other libraries". I don't think you down voted the question.

Comment: Haha, it was tough to win you over to this side. My bad tho, I think I got confused a few times in between your edits because I wasn't sure what part exactly of the whole thing (inheritance/mixin in JS? _.extend vs extend()? extending from Backbone.Model or extending Backbone.Model...) you were really interested in.